# Extract pagination nodes from RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, rabl

I'm using Rails 3.2.18 and RABL 0.10.1.

Right now, I have many index actions through my application that include some pagination information, as well as the collection.

This is what an example of a rendered RABL response looks like:

```
{
  "current_page" => 1,
  "total_pages"  => 1,
  "total_count"  => 2,
  "per_page"     => 1000,
  "links"        => [ {"id" => ...}, {"id" => ...}]
}
```

My `config/initializers/rabl.rb` looks like:

```
# config/initializers/rabl.rb
Rabl.configure do |config|
  config.include_child_root = false
end
```

Here's what the index view for the above example response looks like:

```
# app/views/links/index.rabl
object false

node(:current_page) { @links.current_page }
node(:total_pages)  { @links.num_pages }
node(:total_count)  { @links.total_count }
node(:per_page)     { @links.limit_value }

child(@links => :links) do
  extends 'links/show'
end
```

I have the `current_page`, `total_page`, `total_count`, `per_page` nodes constructed like this for many index actions. I'd like to reduce the duplication.

I was hoping I could use a partial to make things like so:

```
# app/views/shared/pagination.rabl
node(:current_page) {|o| o.current_page }
node(:total_pages)  {|o| o.num_pages }
node(:total_count)  {|o| o.total_count }
node(:per_page)     {|o| o.limit_value }

# app/views/links/index.rabl
object false

partial 'shared/pagination', object: @links

child(@links => :links) do
  extends 'links/show'
end
```

But this winds up winds up throwing an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `current_page' for #<Link:0x007f92387dbc58>
```

I've read the RABL documentation and tried quite a few other methods based on what I read there, but I still can't figure out how to reduce the duplication and still have the original output.

Does anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help and I'll gladly provide any more information that would help.